# Python not able to identify sum(). Returns an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner, using python 3.6, IDE Spyder(Anaconda).
I'm trying to write the first 10 odd numbers using for loop and add them.
Following is the code:

**Input**

```
x = list(range(0,10))
print(x)
a = []

for i in x:
    y = 2*i + 1
    a.append(str(y))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '15', '17', '19']
```

But if I use `print(sum(a))` syntax:

**Input:**

```
x = list(range(0,10))
print(x)
a = []

for i in x:
    y = 2*i + 1
    a.append(str(y))
print(a)
print(sum(a))
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

How to obtain the sum of all the odd numbers listed using sum()?

Comment: Don't append the numbers *as string* into the list if you later want to treat them as numbers.

Comment: `a.append(str(y))` should be `a.append(y)`, or better yet, just do `x = list(range(0,10))` and then `sum(x)` and you're done in two lines.

Comment: @Torxed This code does more than just `list(range(0, 10))`… Though it *can* easily be done in two lines regardless.

Comment: @deceze Sorry, forgot the `2*i + 1` which would require the use of `enumerate()` to get the index and doing list comprehension. Idea still stands that the main issue is the `str(y)` tho :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Just Change **a.append(str(y))**

To **a.append(y)**, now why's the error? It's because you added elements as string, then you use sum operator which is valid only on integers datatype!

Your Corrected Code Will Be Like:

```
x = list(range(0,10)) 
print(x) 
a = [] 
for i in x: 
    y = 2*i + 1
    a.append(y)
print(a) 
print(sum(a))
```